# I cannot create/open a JavaScript project on Visual Studio2017 running on Win7

Tags: javascript, windows, visual-studio

I am developing some JavaScript program on Visual Studio running on Windows10. But, I must use another laptop for a while which is installed Windows7.
I installed VS2017 Community on the laptop, and I copied the all project files from the desktop to the laptop. Then, I found I couldn't open the project (the VS's solution file) because the version is not supported with it(both use VS2017 with same version. What does it mean by that?).

I also tried to create a new empty JavaScript project on the laptop, but I couldn't go beyond the UWP choice menu because the message said this project type was not supported by this install.

So, I researched about it, and some websites say I better install all versions of WindowsSDK from the installer. So, I picked all version of them, and installed. But, I still cannot solve any of the trouble.

My JavaScript program is not using any Windows specific codes. Does Visual Studio requires Windows10 for JavaScript program development? Do I need to install Windows10 and then VS2017 on the laptop if I want to develop a JavaScript base program?

Answer (score 0):

Check your edition of VS2017 on your Windows 10 VM. Click Help, About.

It may be the project template type isn't supported by Community edition. Check the project template type back on your Windows 10 VM as well.

Alternatively, check the version of VS2017 on Windows 7. There have been reported issues of the Community edition missing Web App project templates (see [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/202452/visual-studio-community-2017-1557-web-app-template.html)).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I checked the VS2017 version of both machines, and they were same. I read the link you provided for me. When I try to create a new JavaScript project on VS2017 running on Windows7, I can choose the JavaScript templates for UWA from the initial menu. But, I cannot go beyond the popup menu on which I need to choose the target and minimum platform versions that my Universal Windows applicatioin(my JavaScript program) will support. I installed all versions of WindowsSDKs and tried again and again with diffrent version choices, but it wouldn't let me go...